# Двойное нажатие на кнопку

Tags: javascript, html, css

Спасибо вашему сайту за помощь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас, когда функция выполняется в первый раз, inline свойство `style.display` - пустое.

```js
One.onclick = function() {
  var display = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('content')).display;
  if (display == "none") {
    document.getElementById('content').style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('content').style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
#content {
  border: 2px solid black;
  background: green;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 30px;
  display: none;
}

#One {
  font-size: 50px;
  outline: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<button id="One">Html</button>
<div id="content"> тут скрытый блок</div>
```

Comment: Да, все работает, благодарю вас

Comment: @user362586 Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: Да, я знаю про галочку, просто нужно было какое-то время, чтобы ее поставить